# Approximation for counting the number of simple $s$-$t$ paths in a general graph

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, graph-algorithms, approximation-algorithms, counting-complexity

I have been told that there are some good polynomial time algorithms for approximating the number of simple paths in an directed graph from given starting vertex $s$ to given ending vertex $t$. Does anyone know of a good reference on this subject?

Background: counting the exact number of paths in a general graph is #P-complete but there may exist polynomial time approximations for the problem. I'm especially interested in random approximations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had the same problem e solve using Random Walk.

Comment: @bbejot: See [How hard is counting the number of simple paths between two nodes in a directed graph?](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/423/how-hard-is-counting-the-number-of-simple-paths-between-two-nodes-in-a-directed) The only answer, by jmad, provides a link to a paper that provides indeed a random approximation

Answer (score 1):

This problem should be NP-hard by reducing from the maximum length of s-t paths.

The reduction simply replace every edge by, say, $k$ parallel edges. (If you are uncomfortable with a multi-graph, replace each edge by a path of length 2.) The effect of this is that the number $C_{\ell}$ of paths of length $\ell$ becomes $k^\ell C_{\ell}$. Thus, if $k$ is suitably large, the term corresponding to the longest paths in the original graph will dominate everything else (even if $C_{\ell_{max}}=1$). From there you can easily recover the length of the longest s-t path.